# Question mark operator usage in Lift

Tags: scala, lift

Lift framework provides an [Easy way](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/SiteMap) to define a Sitemap.

I don't quite understand the example it provides.
what does `?` and `/` mean in the following snippet?

```
def siteMap() = SiteMap(Menu(S ? "Home") / "index")
```

Comment: You might want to edit your question to indicate that this is a lift question - scala doesn't have operators per se, and the ? is just a method call, so what it means is entirely dependent on context - in this case, that of Lift's SiteMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ? and / here are methods.

```
/**
   * Get a localized string or return the original string.
   *
   * @param str the string to localize
   *
   * @return the localized version of the string
   *
   * @see # resourceBundles
   */
  def ?(str: String): String = ?!(str, resourceBundles)
```

Menu constructor returns a `PreMenu` type, the `/` method defined in `PreMenu`

```
/**
 * The method to add a path element to the URL representing this menu item
 */
def /(pathElement: String): Menuable with WithSlash = 
  new Menuable(name, linkText, pathElement :: Nil, false, Nil, Nil) with WithSlash
```

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Lift, but by looking at the [ScalaDoc for S](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.1/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/http/S%24object.html) it's clear that `S ? str` returns a localization property (check [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/ResourceBundles/) for more on localization) or in case of not finding the property the string it self.